# LocalDb and SMO - how to choose where to put database files?

Tags: powershell, smo, localdb

I've started to experiment with the SQL Server 2012 feature LocalDb. I'm doing some powershell scripting with SMO against the instances I create, such as creating databases. To do this, I have this function:

```
Function New-Database {
    Param(
        $server,
        $databaseName
    )
    $serverHandle = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($server)
    if($serverHandle.Databases.Name.Contains($databaseName)) {
        throw "Database $databaseName already exists"
    }

    $databaseHandle = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($serverHandle, $databaseName)
    $databaseHandle.Create()
}
```

When using LocalDb, the mdf and ldf files are created in `C:\Users\<username>\`. I want to override this, but I'm failing to find out how. The `$databaseHandle` object has a property `PrimaryFilePath`, but that is read-only. It seems like something that should be dead-simple to do, but I just can't find out how...

**Solution**
Led by the answer below, here is the Powershell calls I needed:

```
$fileGroup = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGroup($databaseHandle, "PRIMARY")
$dataFile = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataFile($fileGroup, "DataFile", $filePath)
$fileGroup.Files.Add($dataFile)
$databaseHandle.FileGroups.Add($fileGroup)
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx

Comment: @DavidBrabant: Well, yes, that tells me how to do it in SQL Management Studio, or by making SQL calls. But in this case I can do neither, I'm constrained to SMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this thread from the SMO Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/fc95664a-9c16-47d0-b7d4-325db0e4d95d/) contains the answer. You just need to translate it to SQL PowerShell syntax (which I believe is just a wrapper to SMO at this point).

Here's the VBScript snippet:

```
databaseHandle.FileGroups.Add(New FileGroup(db, "PRIMARY"))
databaseHandle.FileGroups(0).Files.Add(
    New DataFile(db.FileGroups(0), "TestName", "D:\SqlBancos\Teste\Teste1.mdf"))
```

Comment: Thanks! For completeness sake, I added the powershell syntax above.

Comment: Thanks, great to see the complete answer!