# Using "starts with" in powershell script instead of contains?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

In my current powershell script I have hash table with values. Am using 
this syntax

```
$x = $f.contains("$k")
```

but I figured recently that am having problems with this approach I was wondering if powershell has something that says "starts with," or related, that would search thru the hash table with "starts with" instead of `contains`

Example of the hash table:

```
"bio.txt" = "server1\datafiles\bio";
etc.......
```

**EDIT** Sample from comments

```
foreach ($key in $filehash.keys) { 
    $path = $filehash.get_Item($key)
    $filecount = 0
    foreach ($file in $FileArray) { 
        if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt($(GetDate).adddays(-1))) { 
            [string] $k = $key.ToLower()
            [string] $f = $file.name.ToLower() 
            if ($x = $f.contains("$k")) { } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you searching for the keys or the values?

Comment: the example that caused this problem was lets say I had

Comment: "bio.txt" = "server1\datafiles\bio";

Comment: "bio.csv" = "server1\datafiles\bio\csv";

Comment: Use "Shift + return" for a new line

Comment: it would move both files to the one location which ever it hits first in the search

Comment: shokran jazak allah :)

Comment: afwan. wa eyakum :-)
I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you please post your code and put more explanation to enable me or someone else in here to help you.

As an example, have a look at this post and see how they've given helpful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998233/localdb-and-smo-how-to-choose-where-to-put-database-files

Comment: foreach ($key in $filehash.keys)
{
 $path = $filehash.get_Item($key)
 $filecount = 0
 foreach ($file in $FileArray)
 {
  
  if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt($(GetDate).adddays(-1)))
  {
   [string] $k = $key.ToLower()
   [string] $f = $file.name.ToLower()
   
   if ($x = $f.contains("$k"))
   {
                        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `-like` to check if a string starts with `yourvalue`. I rewrote your sample in the comments to use it:

```
$filehash.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
    #$_ is now current object from hashtable(like foreach)
    #$_.key is key and $_.value is path
    $filecount = 0
    foreach ($file in $FileArray) {
        if ( ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))) -and ($file.name -like "$($_.Key)*") ) {
            #process file

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach ($key in $filehash.keys)
{
 $path = $filehash.get_Item($key)
 $filecount = 0
 foreach ($file in $FileArray)
 {
  
  if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt($(GetDate).adddays(-1)))
  {
   [string] $k = $key.ToLower()
   [string] $f = $file.name.ToLower()
   
   if ($x = $f.contains("$k"))
   {
                        }

Comment: instead of using contains, am wondering if I can change it to starts with or something similar to it

Comment: Can't you just use: `if ($f -like "$k*") { #process if filename starts with $k }` ?  See updated answer

Comment: if ($x = $f.StartsWith("$k"))

this is what I was looking for ... thanks everyone :)